# Do we have different assumptions for point estimate and interval estimate?

Tags: central-limit-theorem, consistency, point-estimation

The procedure for interval estimate and point estimate appears to be based on the central limit theorem. Is it a correct assertion.

Comment: It is difficult for people to answer questions that are based explicitly on false assumptions, as this one is, and even more difficult when the question is broadly stated and vague.  Please edit your title and the text to make your question more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't a question here, but the distinction you cite is not correct. Point estimates rely on *consistency*, a *first-order property*, such as the strong law of large numbers, which guarantees (almost surely) that the estimate approaches the true value as sample size approaches infinity. A consistent estimator will approach the true value almost surely. That is all you need for a point estimator.

Interval estimates rely on *second-order properties* that quantify the spread of the estimator or its distribution. In practice, this means either relying on an exact sampling distribution (this is rare) or relying on asymptotic results such as different versions of the central limit theorem, or extreme value theorems (for extremal estimators).

Comment: Your answer appears implicitly to assume that all point estimates are made using maximum likelihood and evaluated using the principles appropriate to ML theory. This is very much not the case.  The same comments apply to your assertions about interval estimates.

Comment: @whuber yes, I had ML theory in mind when writing this to contrast the applications of SLLN vs CLT in point and interaval estimates, contrary to what the OP has stated. I did not go into Bayesian estimation (although I did not make this explicit in my response). Perhaps you can add a comment or post on some inconsistent point estimators and perhaps discuss credibility and likelihood intervals. I just wanted to keep this focused on the most common case of frequentist estimation.

Comment: Surely consistency & second-order properties are generally relevant frequentist considerations for estimates, & not only for maximum-likehood ones - e.g. for the UMVUE estimate for $\theta$ from a uniform distribution on $(0,\theta)$.

Comment: @Scortchi This is all irrelevant with small samples where it is rare for asymptotic properties to hold and one should always suspect they might not. Thus the assertion "this is all you need for a point estimator" effectively throws out the vast majority of statistical theory and statistical tests as well as eliminating all possibility of statistical analysis of small samples.

Comment: @whuber There is a distinction between estimation and inference. A point estimate, per se, does not say anything about its uncertainty nor its bias (especially relevant in small samples, as you indicated). Statistical tests require second-order properties to specify a rejection region - read: *interval*. However, unbiasedness is not a universal desideratum (MLEs are not generally unbiased), but we would hope that as we collect more data, we our estimator stongly converges toward the true value...otherwise, what's the point of the sample? The OP is not asking about hypotheisi testing.

Comment: @subhashc.davar Glad this helped you. If your question is answered, please tick this answer so it's marked as complete.

Comment: Eupraxis1981 really thankful. Your profile does not indicate email address. I have worked out some improvement in Hunter Schmidt formulas and doing a few papers. Would you like to join me in this endeavor. I lack technical side of statistics though have done a few papers on meta-analytic formulas

Comment: @subhashc.davar lets discuss in chat. See "Research Discussion" room. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11955/research-discussion

Comment: @subhashc.davar actually, I have to head out. My research email is beyer1981@hotmail.com. Send me a description of what you are working on, whith whom (including institution), and what kinds of data you are asking me to analyze. I generally don't work on independent projects, so it would need to be legit through a university. I'll see if I think I can be of use to you...I don't know all types of statistical techiques but I have a good basis in the major types.

Comment: @Eupraxis: A point estimate per se doesn't say anything about its consistency either. I'm not quite sure what "rely on" & "all you need" mean here, but even considering only asymptotic properties of estimators, efficiency may well be a reason to choose one rather than another of the many consistent estimators; & efficiency requires second-order properties to be taken into account even when you're not planning hypothesis tests or the construction of confidence intervals.

Comment: @scortchi I totally agree that other considerations come into play when picking an estimator. The OPs question was more about foundations. Point estimation " works" because of consistency whereas interval estimation requires not just consistency but convergence in distribution too. Of course there are other things that come into play in practical situations but firs and second order convergence are necessary

Comment: @Eupraxis 1981 I am not very clear about the term consistency. does it indicate the outcome of say mean here is similar (or equivalent) following a resampling of data. I presume that you are trying to respond in terms of central limit theorem and law of statistical-regularity (convergence).

Comment: @subhashc.davar what you just described is the "estimator variance". Consistency is not a resampling property but an asymptotic property. In a nutshell, a consistent estimator is one that converges to the population value as your sample size gets larger - it is not the same thing as the central limit theorem, which concerns itself with sums of independent random variables. Consistency is a more general property that simply says that your esimator will approach the true value...eventually. The speed of that convergence depends on the efficiency and variability of the esimator.

Comment: @subhashc.davar no luck finding your papers on either site. Shoot me some links and I'll take a look...sturctural equation modeling is not an area I do a lot of work in.